# Finding a value in an excel Sheet that always moves

Tags: vba, excel

What Im doing now:

```
y.sheets("TP").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = x.sheets("DR").Range("C3")
```

How my data sheet looks:

> A1=Name1, F1=Name2, K1=Name3
>
> A2:E2 = Details on Name1, F2:J2 = Details on Name2 . . .

My problem is that sometimes I'm adding another Names, and then I need to retype the code.

So How can I write the code, that if NameX and his details are moving, the whole code would move with him/

Comment: Why can't you use the column headers as indicators for what row/column indexes to point your logic at?

Comment: You can use **INDEX + MATCH** to find your row (or maybe even **VLOOKUP**, depending on your setup)

Comment: I need to use a code, cause its updated with a lot of data every day. @Zac

Comment: I don't know how to do that @soohoonigan

Comment: You can still use things like **INDEX + MATCH** in your code.. have a look at `Application.WorksheetFunction`

Comment: I down vote because the question is too vague and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Named Ranges](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmquickly_name_a_cell_or_range_of_cells).

Define a name for each range or column you want to access in VBA. You can access it in VBA with `Range("YourName")`

Example based on

> A1=Name1, F1=Name2, K1=Name3
>      A2:E2 = Details on Name1, F2:J2 = Details on Name2 . . .

Define names for …

- column A: `Name1`
- column F: `Name2`
- column K: `Name3`

So you can access `A2:E2` by something like `Range("Name1").Rows(2).Resize(1, 5)`

Whenever you insert new columns the names `NameX` will stick with the data and move too.

---

Alternatively define a name for `A2:E2` like `DetailsName1` to access it with `Range("DetailsName1")`